# Unable to decrypt AES-256 (CBC) - Malformed Utf-8 data

Tags: cryptojs

I've gone through several CrytoJS examples but haven't been able to make decryption work for me. I need to decode something for which a key (13 characters in length, just in case it's important) and iv (16 length after Base64 decode) I've been provided. I found this PHP example that works perfectly (these won't work if you run them - the key has been changed, of course :) ):

```
$encrypted = urldecode('6x5Mex1DqqFK0Z9F%2F6W1FNB55UM%2Baoyjw6NgTwDDmHpVytJXNyQsA3J8jh3R4qt5MbKITzIORGLtgmfknUNLaBhBaBO%2F8GiFPT8A6wVgtQ6YOXkJHG8S9VKYgrN9MCeT0e8mbWMNfkkJ0ips4K87ZNzC6Lb5dbT1%2BRMw%2BpmCP7M8%2FwiBMdJZ%2FdINblg%2FapHtaqv6TUBRukB%2FEJWgGFB86h5fJ8VNZKssWtx35gLo6IHai6GTQpyS%2FNeq5ZbX%2BJwcnCKOzudHsdAyxk%2BQYltupFNBXBzxxW%2Fiixtew7uNtRJQfy2epcx0SOqRGKQfJrRReFWvldJWSKz%2Bv0aRMdZWCVRHovcwPLdXNWSK%2Brs7G0LCnjji4RyqzU9DTy%2BijA1Xx3xVmOxXysCkvqXNg2P0LJ0O0qLJF9lfQb%2FrrPH3h3lB0a7737CTzQh5kuqK%2FNabfV8qLNyV6cJ5oQWMfXw4LRxDIeK9Me8Fnb2K44uC39Q%3D');

$iv = urldecode('MkQ4NUFGNkVBNjIwMEY5OQ%3D%3D');

$secretKey = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";

// decrypt the body... 
$decrypted = trim(
    mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        substr(sha1($secretKey), 0, 32),
        base64_decode($encrypted),
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 
        base64_decode($iv)
    ), "\0..\32");

print("Decrypted: $decrypted");
```

And now I'm trying to do something similar in CryptoJS, but keep getting the error `Malformed Utf-8 data`:

```
var encrypted = decodeURIComponent('6x5Mex1DqqFK0Z9F%2F6W1FNB55UM%2Baoyjw6NgTwDDmHpVytJXNyQsA3J8jh3R4qt5MbKITzIORGLtgmfknUNLaBhBaBO%2F8GiFPT8A6wVgtQ6YOXkJHG8S9VKYgrN9MCeT0e8mbWMNfkkJ0ips4K87ZNzC6Lb5dbT1%2BRMw%2BpmCP7M8%2FwiBMdJZ%2FdINblg%2FapHtaqv6TUBRukB%2FEJWgGFB86h5fJ8VNZKssWtx35gLo6IHai6GTQpyS%2FNeq5ZbX%2BJwcnCKOzudHsdAyxk%2BQYltupFNBXBzxxW%2Fiixtew7uNtRJQfy2epcx0SOqRGKQfJrRReFWvldJWSKz%2Bv0aRMdZWCVRHovcwPLdXNWSK%2Brs7G0LCnjji4RyqzU9DTy%2BijA1Xx3xVmOxXysCkvqXNg2P0LJ0O0qLJF9lfQb%2FrrPH3h3lB0a7737CTzQh5kuqK%2FNabfV8qLNyV6cJ5oQWMfXw4LRxDIeK9Me8Fnb2K44uC39Q%3D');
var iv = decodeURIComponent('MkQ4NUFGNkVBNjIwMEY5OQ%3D%3D');


var encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted);
var ive = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(iv);

var secretOne = "CLICKBANKINFS";
var secretTwo = CryptoJS.SHA1(secretOne);
var secretThree = secretTwo.toString().substring(0,32);

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, secretThree, 
    { 
        iv: ive,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }
);

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

The encrypted text and iv are both Base64 encoded. I'm not sure how this is to be handled exactly. I've seen several implementations of CryptoJS decryption and have tried several combinations but nothing worked for me.

Some help, please? :)

Comment: Where in your JavaScript code do you use `iv`? Also, take a look at `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse`.

Comment: @Blender The JS code is right after the PHP code. Yes, I did look at `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse` and did fiddle with it, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I know it's right after, but you're posting it as an almost-functional equivalent of the PHP code. In your JS code, you never actually use the `iv` variable. I would start by first figuring out what *exact* values are passed into `mcrypt_decrypt` and how you can transform your `key` and `iv` into them from within your JS code. As it is now, your code doesn't derive the actual encryption key (`substr(sha1($secretKey), 0, 32)`).

Comment: @Blender Ah, I mistakenly passed the key where I should have passed the `iv` variable. But that's my question: Do I need a functionally equivalent code to PHP? I presented it because it's out of the docs of the service I need to use, and they don't have a JS example. Do I need the sha1 stuff, for example? I'm just very confused. Can you point me to a tutorial/example that will help me decrypt for my case?

Comment: You just need to see exactly what's passed into `mcrypt_decrypt`. Save all the arguments as intermediate variables, see what they all mean in the PHP documentation, and dump them out. The actual key used for decryption is whatever `substr(sha1($secretKey), 0, 32)` outputs, so that's the only key you need. Similarly for the IV and the ciphertext. To make it easier to pass between the PHP and JS code, `base64_encode()` the key, IV and ciphertext and `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse` them in your JS. It'd be helpful if you could post actually working code.

Comment: @Blender By actual working code you mean provide the key as well?

Comment: Just something that runs. It's a bit of effort to produce my own test key and corresponding test ciphertext just to make your code run.

Comment: @Blender Okay, I've edited the JS code and now it gives me nothing in output. Please have a look if you can, otherwise I'll roll with the PHP code and use an Ajax request. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var secretThree = secretTwo.toString().substring(0, 32));

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, secretThree,
```

To:

```
var secretThree = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(secretTwo.toString().substring(0, 32)));

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: encrypted}, secretThree,
```

1. The first parameter has to be an object *or* a base64-encoded JavaScript string. Passing just `encrypted` makes the `decrypt` call silently fail. You can either do what I have above or remove the following line from your to leave the ciphertext as a base64-encoded JavaScript string:

   ```
   var encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted);
   ```
2. JavaScript in general has very strange support for byte arrays, so the CryptoJS wrappers are required for everything to work properly. Even `secretThree`, which is entirely ASCII `[0-9a-f]`.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks so much! :-)

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure how you arrived at the values for `key`, `iv` and `ciphertext` used in this example. Could you please explain? :)

Comment: Thank you! JS is a mess, really! :D